# Dell Blade DRAC remote: Unable to connect to RAC

Tags: dell, drac

I'm attempting to remotely administer a set of Dell blade servers: PE M600 and M605 with iDRAC5.

On my Windows 8.1 laptop I installed [DRAC Tools v7.3](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=K7F2N). I can successfully remotely manage the M1000e CMC, as well as some non-blade servers (that have iDRAC 7 Enterprise), via `racadm -r <ip or hostname> -u <username> -p <password> <command> <args>`, e.g.:

```
C:\> racadm -r cmc.example.com -u admin -p calvin getconfig -g cfgRacSecurity
cfgRacSecCsrKeySize=1024
cfgRacSecCsrCommonName=
cfgRacSecCsrOrganizationName=
cfgRacSecCsrOrganizationUnit=
cfgRacSecCsrLocalityName=
cfgRacSecCsrStateName=
cfgRacSecCsrCountryCode=US
cfgRacSecCsrEmailAddr=
```

However, I cannot get any commands to work when attempting to administer any of the blades:

```
C:\> racadm -r blade0-idrac.example.com -u admin -p calvin getconfig -g cfgRacSecurity
ERROR: Unable to connect to RAC at specified IP address.
```

Administering via the web GUI takes forever and is generally unreliable, it would be much easier to handle configurations via CLI, especially in bulk. **I'd like to be able to administer the blades via RACADM remotely.**

To help troubleshoot, things that are known:

- Blades are M600 and M605
- Enclosure is M1000e
- I can ping the blades (blade0-idrac.example.com in the example above) from the remote laptop.
- The blades' HTTPS web management is working and is accessible from the remote laptop.
- From the CMC (logging in via SSH/telnet/etc), `$ connect -m server-1` starts the console session but never provides a prompt, i.e. it is stuck at `Connected to server-1. Escape character is '^\'.`
- SSH into the blades works just fine, I am presented with SMASH-CLP (really don't want to use this)
- CMC firmware is at version 5.00.A00
- Blade iDRAC firmware is at version 1.65 Build 1

Answer (score 0):

(iwork4dell) I wonder if you just have the wrong credentials.  The default user name is "root" not "admin".  You can change the quick deploy settings to change the account 2 username and password but I think you have to press OK on the LCD when you insert the blade.  Are you sure the blade iDRACs have IP addresses?  can you ping them and ssh to them?

Comment: The credentials I have in the post are for example only, and I am able to log in successfully via other avenues. iDRACs have IP addresses: confirmed in CMC GUI/CLI and on the LCD, they are pingable, I can access the iDRAC web interface, and can SSH into the SMASH-CLP CLI for each iDRAC instance.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Drac 5.  I'll forward this issue to support.